# How to set up a promotion to offer a free soap when two products when two products from a specific range are purchased

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm looking to set up a promotion on Magento 2.1 as follows; buy two products from a specific range, with a value of £20 or more and receive a free product.

There are products within this range that’d we’d like to exclude so I’m looking to select the products that need to be bought by SKU.

I’ve tried a few options but it’s allowing a free gift to be added when products from other ranges are added along with only one of the products from the promotion range and the value is over £20.